# Why would my switch's case be correct but the output is not?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, switch-statement

I have an ability on my player that highlights enemies for a brief time, all works well for this. I decided to make this upgradable so the higher the level of the ability the more stuff gets highlighted.

- Level 0 (base level) enemies are highlighted.
- Level 1 enemies & Items are highlighted.
- Level 2 enemies, items & special items are highlighted.
- Level 3 enemies, items, special items & hidden areas are highlighted.

To do this, I thought a switch running in an IEnumerator (Coroutine) would be the most efficient way. A function calls the coroutine and depending on the level the player has for the ability a  switch should handle the the actual ability functionality (see code).

Here's the code:

```cs
public void CatsEye(){
  if (player.cateye >= 1 && !catsEyeActive) {

    player.cateye -= 1;
    StartCoroutine("CatEye");
      // Debug.Log("Cateye Active");

  }
}


IEnumerator CatEye(){
  catsEyeActive = true;

    switch(player.cateyeLevel){
      case 3:
      if (itemObject != null && enemyObject != null
          && specialObject != null && hiddenObject != null) {
        hidden.isOutlined = true;
        special.isOutlined = true;
        enemyData.isOutlined = true;
        item.isOutlined = true;
      }
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(15f);
      if (itemObject != null && enemyObject != null) {
        hidden.isOutlined = false;
        special.isOutlined = false;
        enemyData.isOutlined = false;
        item.isOutlined = false;
      }
      catsEyeActive = false;
      break;


      case 2:
        if (itemObject != null && enemyObject != null && specialObject != null) {
          special.isOutlined = true;
          enemyData.isOutlined = true;
          item.isOutlined = true;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(15f);
        if (itemObject != null && enemyObject != null) {
          special.isOutlined = false;
          enemyData.isOutlined = false;
          item.isOutlined = false;
        }
        catsEyeActive = false;
      break;


      case 1:
        if (itemObject != null && enemyObject != null) {
          enemyData.isOutlined = true;
          item.isOutlined = true;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(15f);
        if (itemObject != null && enemyObject != null) {
          enemyData.isOutlined = false;
          item.isOutlined = false;
        }
        catsEyeActive = false;
      break;


      case 0:
        if (enemyObject != null) {
          enemyData.isOutlined = true;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(15f);
        if (enemyObject != null) {
          enemyData.isOutlined = false;
        }
        catsEyeActive = false;
      break;
    }
}
```

The issue is that even with the `player.cateyeLevel` set at 0, the ability is acting as if it's at level 3 and is highlighting everything.

The `player.cateyeLevel` refers to a player script, but there are no variables set there that would be the cause of the issue. In fact, if anything, the `player.cateyeLevel` variable for this ability has been set to 0. There's also no `PlayerPrefs` storing the `player.cateyeLevel`, so it isn't that either.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the coroutine, although I would call the function directly as StartCoroutine(CatEye());. Put a Debug.Log(player.cateyeLevel.ToString()) call just before the switch statement to check your logic. If it prints "0" as you expect there must be some other script altering the isOutline properties. Then do more Debug.Log() calls or use the debugger.

Comment: @AndulfGames-AndersBjerin Tried your suggestion but the same issue occurs :(  there's nothing in the outline.cs file that would cause the issue as all it does is enable or disable a shader effect on the GameObject if the isOutlined bool is true. no connection to the player.cateyeLevel variable. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Strange, in that case, I would add a breakpoint on the first line in the CatEye() function and step manually in the debugger to check what is happening. Adding a lot of temporary Debug.Log() calls is also an alternative... happy hunting.

Comment: It seems like you have player.cateye at the top and player.cateyeLevel in your switch. Those are different variables. Also, you might consider swapping out the switch for something like `hidden.isOutlined = player.cateyeLevel > 2` - I think that would result in less code that's easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @VicF They are indeed different variables,  player.cateye refers to the amount of catseyes the player has to use and cateyeLevel refers to the level of the cateye ability itself. I'm still fairly novice with programming so would it be possible for you to explain why swapping out the switch for what you suggested would be a good approach and how exactly it works using that method please?

Comment: @Twisted I was just commenting - there's nothing really wrong with what you did. I like the way you wrote it below - it looks much cleaner. I was just saying that writing `if (x && y) {z = true;}` can sometimes be easier to read as `z = (x && y);`. When you have `switch` cases that are setting a bunch of the same variables based on the value, it can often be consolidated down to simpler set statements. Coding is as much art as science - and the only real measurement of success is working code that meets its requirements.

Comment: @Twisted For example, the first `foreach` in the code below could be:

     foreach (GameObject enemyObject in enemyObjects)
     {
        enemyData = enemyObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();

        if (enemyObject != null)
        {
           enemyData.isOutlined = (catsEyeActive && player.cateyeLevel == 0);
        }
       }

Comment: @VicF I get you now and I agree, if it works and meets the requirements it's success but having readable/understandable code is also, for me a must. Nothing worse than coming back to code after a couple weeks and having no clue what you're looking at. Thanks for your input that lead me to my correct output :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by rewriting the the functionality entirely, the new code for anyone interested uses Update for the main bulk of the outlining and the coroutine is only there for timing now.

```
    void Update()
    {

      enemyObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
      foreach(GameObject enemyObject in enemyObjects){
        enemyData = enemyObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (enemyObject != null) {
          if (catsEyeActive && player.cateyeLevel == 0) {
            enemyData.isOutlined = true;
          }
        }
      }

      items = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Item");
      foreach(GameObject itemObject in items){
        item = itemObject.GetComponent<Item>();
        if (item != null) {
          if (catsEyeActive && player.cateyeLevel == 1) {
            enemyData.isOutlined = true;
            item.isOutlined = true;
          }
        }
      }

      specials = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Special");
      foreach(GameObject specialObject in specials){
        special = specialObject.GetComponent<Special>();
        if (special != null) {
          if (catsEyeActive && player.cateyeLevel == 2) {
            enemyData.isOutlined = true;
            item.isOutlined = true;
            special.isOutlined = true;
          }
        }
      }

      hiddens = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Hidden");
      foreach(GameObject hiddenObject in hiddens){
        hidden = hiddenObject.GetComponent<Hidden>();
        if (hidden != null) {
          if (catsEyeActive && player.cateyeLevel == 3 ) {
            enemyData.isOutlined = true;
            item.isOutlined = true;
            special.isOutlined = true;
            hidden.isOutlined = true;
          }
        }
      }

      
    }


    public void CatsEye(){
      if (player.cateye >= 1 && !catsEyeActive) {    
        player.cateye -= 1;
        StartCoroutine("CatEye");
      }
    }


    IEnumerator CatEye(){
      catsEyeActive = true;
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(15f);
      catsEyeActive = false;
    }
```